# Jump to using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I am fetching an XML document from a third party (so I cannot change it) which contains around 1000 records. I am translating this using XSLT to only show the user 50 records at a time. I can control which records are shown by checking the position e.g.

```
xsl:if test="not(position() &lt; 101)"

xsl:if test="position() &lt; 150"
```

The user would prefer to jump to a value rather than scrolling through page by page until they find it. The rest of the records should still show after the jump to value so I don't want to check for an exact match.  I initially thought that I could do a string comparison e.g.

```
xsl:if test="@key >= 'jumpto'"
```

but this is not supported in 1.0. Any ideas how to achieve what I want?

The XML is quite large to post and the data is confidential. But imagine it is a simple XML file with just a name e.g.

```
<contacts>
    <name>alan</name>
    <name>brad</name>
    <name>chad</name>
    <name>dave</name>
    <name>eric</name>
</contacts>
```

I want to only show the data starting from dave onwards and I can pass dave to the XSL document.

Comment: Without a sample of the XML input it's going to be awfully hard for anybody to help you.

Comment: The XML is quite large to post and the data is confidential. But imagine it is a simple XML file with just a name e.g. <contacts> <name>alan</name><name>brad</name><name>chad</name><name>dave</name><name>eric</name>...etc and I want to only show the data starting from dave onwards and I can pass dave to the XSL document.

Comment: Edit your post and include enough sample XML to understand the problem.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete solution that shows how to compare two strings for "greater or equal" in XSLT 1.0. :)

Answer (score 2):

XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:param name="p">dave</xsl:param>

  <xsl:template match="contacts">
    <out>
      <xsl:apply-templates 
        select="name[. = $p] | name[. = $p]/following-sibling::name"/>
    </out>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="name">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<out>
  <name>dave</name>
  <name>eric</name>
</out>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following transform

- uses the identity rule to copy everything as is (we might avoid here, but I suspect your input is much more complicated)
- overrides the **contacts** element and keeps only the wanted **name** nodes (the node with given `$onward` or any node for which the preceding sibling **name** has the given `$onward`)

[XSLT  1.0]

```
 <xsl:stylesheet  version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:param name="onward" select="'dave'"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" /> 
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="contacts">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | 
                name[.=$onward or preceding-sibling::name=$onward]"/>
        </xsl:copy> 
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

By default (`$onward='dave'`) produces:

```
<contacts>
   <name>dave</name>
   <name>eric</name>
</contacts>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this (I assume that the `name` s are sorted and you want to show all `name` elements starting from the first, whose value is greater or equal to that of `'dave'`):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:my="my:my">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <my:Start>dave</my:Start>

 <xsl:param name="pStart" select="document('')/*/my:Start"/>

 <xsl:template match="name">
  <xsl:variable name="vThis" select="."/>

  <xsl:for-each select=". | $pStart">
   <xsl:sort/>

   <xsl:if test=
    "position() = 2 and . = $vThis">
    <xsl:copy-of select="$vThis"/>
   </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<contacts>
    <name>alan</name>
    <name>brad</name>
    <name>chad</name>
    <name>dave</name>
    <name>eric</name>
</contacts>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<name>dave</name>
<name>eric</name>
```

**If the transformation is applied on this XML document** (note: there isn't a `name` with value `'dave'`):

```
<contacts>
    <name>alan</name>
    <name>brad</name>
    <name>chad</name>
    <name>dave2</name>
    <name>eric</name>
</contacts>
```

**again the correct result -- every `name` with value greater or equal to `'dave'` -- is produced**:

```
<name>dave2</name>
<name>eric</name>
```

**Explanation**:

Here I have shown a "poor man's XPath 1.0 + XSLT 1.0 implementation of string comparison.

The nodes containing the two strings are sorted. Then the node in the second position has string value greater or equal to that of the node in the first position.